# Loading a tsv with just 1 column causes whitespace problem in table

Tags: mysql

I have a spreadsheet.  It looks like this.

x.tsv

```
phone_number
555-555-5555
555-444-4444
555-333-3333
555-222-2222
```

I want load it into a table that looks like this.

```
|phone_number|
 ------------
```

it's varchar(20) datatype, and I am using MySQL 5.6.

My desired output is this

```
|phone_number|
 ------------
|555-555-5555|
 ------------
|555-444-4444|
 ------------
|555-333-3333|
 ------------
|555-222-2222|
 ------------
```

What I am getting is this:

```
|phone_number|
 ------------
 |555-555-5555
 ------------
|555-444-4444
 ------------
|555-333-3333
 ------------
 |555-222-2222
 ------------
```

and data from the field is not matching data from other fields that is should.

What I have tried.

```
mysql>load data local infile 'x.tsv'
...   into table phone_numbers
...   fields terminated by "\t"
...   lines terminated by "\n"
...   ignore 1 lines;


mysql>load data local infile 'x.tsv'
...   into table phone_numbers
...   fields terminated by "\t"
...   lines terminated by "\r"
...   ignore 1 lines;


mysql>load data local infile 'x.tsv'
...   into table phone_numbers
...   fields terminated by "\t"
...   ignore 1 lines;


mysql>load data local infile 'x.tsv'
...   into table phone_numbers
...   ignore 1 lines;

mysql>load data local infile 'x.tsv'
...   into table phone_numbers
...   lines terminated by "\r"
...   ignore 1 lines;
```

and

```
mysql>update phone_numbers
...   set phone_number = trim(phone_number);
```

nothing worked. I searched for an answer on google and bing.  None found.

Comment: Can you Post a snipset from the csv and the create from table on sqlfiddle

Comment: @BerndBuffen sorry for the late response.  Forthcoming.

Comment: I simulated the same using a small csv file and there is no zig zag display of cell values. Can you post your csv file as it is to check.